# html select size or height do not work on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, select, size

A simple code:

```
<select size=5 style='height:100px;'>
<option value='1'>one</option>
<option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
```

Desktop browsers will show a 100px height list with 2 visible elements.
Chrome and Safari for iPad show a drop-down list with no visible elements.
I have found in google some discussions about it, they are from 2010 and without a solution - they say that this does not break w3c specifications. I can agree that it was ok for old little 320x240 smartphones.
Is it **still** not working on modern 10" 2160x1620 iPads?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Is it possible to make mobile safari or chrome to draw <select size=N> like desktop browsers do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in webkit browsers.

The simplest way to get it to work just how you like it in Chrome and Safari would be to manually specify the styling the select itself.

```css
select {
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<select size="3">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">op1</option>
  <option value="2">op2</option>
  <option value="3">op3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Make sure to give each row 18px, so if you have the size set to 3 the height would be 18*3 px if it was 6 rows (size = 6) 18*6 px, also try `min-height`

Comment: However, the above does NOT work for me (on Android).  So, I'm still looking for a workaround for this problem.  (Maybe conditionalize CSS, based on mobile indicator.?!  But, I'm not fluent enough in CSS to understand how to do that.)  Also, I note the author above says to TRY min-height...clearly he is erroneously GUESSING at an inadequate solution.